# How to replace integer values in pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  1  0  1  1
b  1  0  1  6  3
c  0  1  0  1  2
d  5  1  1  0  8
e  1  3  2  8  0
```

I want to replace values that is below 6 `<=5` with 0. So my output should be as follows.

```
   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  6  0
c  0  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0  8
e  0  0  0  8  0
```

I was trying to do this using the following code.

```
df['a'].replace([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0)
df['b'].replace([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0)
df['c'].replace([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0)
df['d'].replace([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0)
df['e'].replace([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0)
```

However, I am sure that there is a more easy way of doing this task in pandas.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `mask`

```
df=df.mask(df<=5,0)
df
Out[380]: 
   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  6  0
c  0  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0  8
e  0  0  0  8  0
```

Answer (score 3):

For performance, I recommend `np.where`. You can assign the array back inplace using sliced assignment (`df[:] = ...`).

```
df[:] = np.where(df < 6, 0, df)
df

   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  6  0
c  0  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0  8
e  0  0  0  8  0
```

---

Another option involves `fillna`:

```
df[df>=6].fillna(0, downcast='infer')

   a  b  c  d  e
a  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  6  0
c  0  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0  8
e  0  0  0  8  0
```

Comment: Didn't know we can use np where on the entire df. Very nice :)

Comment: @anky_91 Happy my post taught you something new!